# multiplicator operation bash issue

Tags: bash, shell

from stdin I read string and if it's like this:

"numberOne * numberTwo"

I have to execute the multiplicator between numberOne and numberTwo.

This is my code:

```
read string
regex2="^[1-9]+ \*{1,1} [1-9]+$"

    if [[ $string =~ $regex2 ]]; then

         val=1
         val1=`echo $string|cut -d " " -f 1`
         val2=`echo $string|cut -d " " -f 3`

         ((val=$val1*$val2))#comment

         echo $val
    fi
```

but I get two errors:

1) on the line where calculate the operation `((val=$val1*$val2))`, it says `syntax error : arithmetic operator invalid`

2) where , by shell , I insert the input string, for example `3 * 2` on shell it prints a list of files, then I thought it was for jolly character "*", and for this reason I substuited the input string with this:

```
3 \* 2
```

but the result doesn't change

Comment: `echo $string` is evil.

Comment: Also, your regexes don't match the number `10`, since they don't allow any `0`s at all.

Comment: ...and yes, the problem *was* the `*`, but no, typing `3 \* 2` didn't do anything different; unless you pass the `-r` argument to read, it discards backslashes (and even if it didn't, that change would make it the string no longer match the regex).

Answer (score 1):

Always, **always** quote your expansions.

`echo $string`, when `$string` contains a `*` surrounded by whitespace, treats that `*` as a glob, replacing it with a list of filenames in the current directory. Your filenames are not likely to be part of a legitimate math operation.

Use `echo "$string"` instead, **if** you must use `echo` at all; `printf '%s\n' "$string"` is the alternative that works in corner cases where `echo` fails (and/or behaves in ways unspecified by POSIX).

---

That said, there's no legitimate reason to use `cut` here at all; your regex will split your string into pieces perfectly well on its own.

```
regex2='^([1-9][0-9]*) [*] ([1-9][0-9]*)$'
read -r string

if [[ $string =~ $regex2 ]]; then
     val=$(( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} * ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ))

     echo "$val"
fi
```

...and even if you couldn't do that, it would be a better practice to use `read`:

```
read val1 _ val2 <<<"$string"
echo "$(( val1 * val2 ))"
```